# How to parse this date format

Tags: java, parsing, date

Hi folks I am trying to parse this format but not able to it .

Format : Fri Oct 21 2011 08:45:00 GMT 0530 (IST)

SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz ZZZZ")

Can some one explain me what is wrong in this ?

Comment: That `0530` has to be in RFC 822 format `+0530` in order to get it parsed as such. You can't parse it without manipulating the string beforehand.

Comment: I did change it to +0530 but still I am not able to parse it         Fri Oct 21 2011 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)                                      new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z (Z)")

Answer (score 5):

The format for your `zzz` is incorrect; [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) show that it needs to be in this format: `GMT-05:30`.

Also, since you have parentheses around the `Z` parameter, you need parentheses in your format string.

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z (Z)")
println sdf.parse("Fri Oct 21 2011 08:45:00 GMT+05:30 (IST)")
> Fri Oct 21 02:45:00 EDT 2011
```

Comment: Problem is I am getting this as input from a api                            Fri Oct 21 2011 08:00:00 GMT 0530 (IST) and I cannot change the input

Comment: @user437066 But you have a string, and you can modify *that* :)